# Where rails 3 keeps default error messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to translate messages and i can't find a file that contained them? I've tried '5.1.3 Translations for the Active Record error_messages_for Helper' from [ruby guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) but that didn't work

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to translate default error messages in rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950248/how-to-translate-default-error-messages-in-rails)

Comment: Rather than starting a new question worded slightly differently than your existing question, just edit the other one and add more info if you need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a en.yml (or whatever_locale.yml) in config/locales/. In it, use the example:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      template:
        header:
          one:   "1 error prohibited this %{model} from being saved"
          other: "%{count} errors prohibited this %{model} from being saved"
        body:    "There were problems with the following fields:"
```

Change "en" by your locale.

Here is a sample:

```
fr:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      format: "your message"
    errors:
      full_messages: "your message"
    errors:
      models:
        full_messages: "your message"
        TABLE_NAME_SINGULAR:
          blank:
              "\"%{attribute}\" is needed"
          attributes:
            ATTRIBUTE:
              blank:
                "Message"
              taken:
                "Message"
```

If you create a new file in "config/locales", I think you have to restart Rails server...